# declaring variable outside subs

Tags: vba, excel

I want to declare a variable outside my 2 subs so that both subs could use the variable when used. So I tried the following but I receive "invalid outside procedure" error.

```
Public strForumURL As String
 Var strForumURL = "x:\docs\...\forum.xls"

sub 1()
AssetURL = strForumURL 
...
end sub

sub 2()
AssetURL = strForumURL 
...
end sub
```

Comment: You cannot *assign* a variable outside procedures. You could use a constant instead, as appears applicable here: `Const strForumURL As String = "x:\docs\...\forum.xls"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `strForumURL` is not going to change, you can set it as a `Public Const` type variable like this.

```
Public Const strForumURL As String = "x:\docs\...\forum.xls"

Sub A1()
    Dim AssetURL As String
    AssetURL = strForumURL
    '... use AssetURL
End Sub

Sub A2()
    Dim AssetURL As String
    AssetURL = strForumURL
    '... use AssetURL
End Sub
```

While you cannot change the string in `strForumURL`, you can use `Replace` to change a part of it when assigning its value to `AssetURL`.

```
    AssetURL = Replace(strForumURL, "http://", "https://")
```